# Using array foreach loop with variables c#

Tags: c#

you very helpful people,

I am currently trying to go through an array of "permissions" run a block of code to check if there have been any changes made and then add the changes as a log on our site.

I currently have the following array (this is a very slimmed down version of the array in question):

```
                string[] permissions = {"CanLogOn",
                "CanAddConsignments",
                "CanAddUsers",
                "CanListBrokers",
                "CanViewBrokers",
                "CanAddBrokers",
                "CanModifyBrokers",
                "CanPutAwayWaste"};
```

This array is saved in the same file just above this snippet of code:

```
            if (dbSecurityGroup.PermissionList != model.PermissionList)
            {
                foreach (string permission in permissions)
                {
                    if (dbSecurityGroup.PermissionList.permission != model.PermissionList.permission)
                    {
                        model.PermissionList.Logs.Add(model.PermissionList.Log(Logger.LogType.Information, permission + " was edited by " + Authentication.AuthenticationManager.LoggedOnUser.Name));
                    };
                };
            }
```

As you can see we have a lot of permissions that are always being added too so we need this to be scalable and check if any of the permissions have changed.

The following code will work as intended but is for a single permission, we are just trying to find a more efficient way of producing this code for many permissions:

```
            if (dbSecurityGroup.PermissionList != model.PermissionList)
            {
                    if (dbSecurityGroup.PermissionList.CanLogOn != model.PermissionList.CanLogOn)
                    {
                        model.PermissionList.Logs.Add(model.PermissionList.Log(Logger.LogType.Information, "Can Log On was edited by " + Authentication.AuthenticationManager.LoggedOnUser.Name));
                    };
            }
```

Any help is more than welcome. (if this method can be used we will also need a RegEx to put a space in between all of the capitals when producing the logs, to change "CanLogOn" to "Can Log On")

Comment: Have you considered to using `Linq` for operations under permissions?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I doubt that´ll help OP much. The main-point here seems to be to get the permissions to be checked by their name. If this is done via linq or a classic loop is another question.

Comment: What kind of type is dbSecurityGroup.PermissionList and model.PermissionList? Is it a List<T>?

Comment: you could use a dictionary with the permissions name as key. Then it´s just something like `if (dbSecurityGroup.PermissionList[permission] != model.PermissionList[permission])`.

Comment: This list is actually a new HashSet if that helps.
I'm very sorry I'm used to using JS, ( I could have done it in JS within seconds and I'm trying to use the same logic with this, but not getting the same outcome) not very used to C# could you explain the "Dictionary" as if I'm  5, please.

Comment: You could change the HashSet to be a List<T> instead. Then you can use the Contains method to check if the permission exist. ```dbSecurityGroup.PermissionList.Contains(permission) != model.PermissionList.Contains(permission)```

Comment: I know it will contain the permission in the list, this is to go through the array and use the permission to check for any changes, if there is then we want it to produce the log.
If it was in JS I would do `permissions.forEach(permission => {dbSecurityGroup.PermissionList.permission != model.PermissionList.permission}`This is the aim of the loop, as mentioned before we already have around 200 permissions which are always increasing, so we want to be able to just add the permission to the array and then it will be logged, & checked on every save and if there are any changes it will be logged.